# What is the right way to serve private routes?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to understand the following security aspect:

If I understand it right, in PHP the URL is routing directly to specific files on the server. e.g. `https://mypage.com/secretFunctions.php` will route to `secretFunctions.php`. If I protect this route trough basic authentication, the authentication will happen before the file is processed and served to the client. In result, only the authenticated user will ever get to see the rendered content.

In case of a client-side node.js app, the whole App.js code is sent to the client and processed there. The URL is always pointing at the same file. The routes defined in that file determine which code snippet will be executed and rendered. Even if I protect any specific route by any kind of authentication, the user will get the whole code anyway.

Is there a way to prevent this? To prevent clients receiving the private code of private routes, as long as they are not authenticated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In node.js the whole App.js code is sent to the client and processed there.

**No, that is not how it works at all.**  When you run node.js and code on your server that code doesn't go to the client - ever.  It just runs on the server.  The client has no access to it.  If you run your node.js app with the command line `node app.js`, then the node executable engine is run and it executes app.js on the server.

In a node.js server, you would not typically define private routes and expect to use them only from your server implementation with no client access.  While, it can be done (using some form of authorization token that only the server knows), you typically wouldn't use a private route at all on your public server.  Instead, rather than requesting a private route on your own self, you would just put the relevant code in a function and call that function directly.  Then, it's entirely private to the server implementation.

Then, app.js would start an http server process and define routes that it wants that server to handler.  When a client comes along and requests a route from the server, then the app.js code (or other modules that it loads) will parse the requested route, map it to a defined handler for that route and execute just the node.js code that is supposed to process that route.  When it's done processing that route, it will send a response.  Depending upon what type of request it is, that response might be a web page that the browser will parse and display or it might be a piece of JSON that is the result of the request or it could be any number of other data types.

The only code that is sent to the client is Javascript code that is embedded in a web page and specifically meant to run inside the browser.  That would not be node.js code and is not your server code.  That would be browser Javascript just like one would use with any back-end framework (node.js is no different than any other framework in that regard).

> Is there a way to prevent this? To prevent clients receiving the private code of private routes, as long as they are not authenticated?

This part of the question is mostly just misguided as it seems to be based on a misunderstanding of how a node.js back-end app server works.  You prevent code going to the client that shouldn't by not sending it to the client in the first place.  The client can't see anything from your server that you don't specifically have a route to handle and send a response.  By default a node.js web server sends NOTHING to the client.  No pages are sent by default.  So, the only thing that is ever sent to a client is a response that you write code specifically to send.  Note, this is different than other back-ends (like Apache) that may be configured to automatically send lots of things that are requested.

> If I understand it right, in PHP the URL is routing directly to specific files on the server. e.g. https://mypage.com/secretFunctions.php will route to secretFunctions.php.

That is PHP.  That is not how node.js web servers work.  For the route `https://mypage.com/secretFunctions.php` to respond at all to the client, you have to define a route in your server code that was specifically coded to respond to the request `/secretFunctions.php` and then you'd define what code should run on the server when that request is received.  No code is sent to the client unless you specifically write code in this route handler to send code to the client that you want to run in the browser.

---

Let me show you a very simple node.js app that responds to three routes (and only three routes).  Let say this is `app.js`:

```
const app = require('express')();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello");
});

app.get('/name', function(req, res) {
    res.send("My name is Bob");
});

app.get('/city', function(req, res) {
    res.send("I am in San Francisco");
});

// start the server
app.listen(80);
```

You start this server with `node app.js`.  When it runs app.js, it initializes an instance of the express framework, registers three route handlers and then starts the web server.

Now, you have a running web server.  Suppose you have a web browser running on the same server and you type this into the URL bar: `http://localhost`.  That will trigger the `'/'` route handler and will display "Hello" in the browser.

Then, you type `http://localhost/name` into the browser.  That will display "My name is Bob" in the browser.

If you type any other route besides these three that are defined here, nothing will be sent to the browser.  It doesn't matter if there's a `contacts.html` file sitting in the same directory.  If there isn't a specific coded route to handle a request, nothing is sent.  So, no private code is every sent by default.

Now, there are ways to instruct your server to automatically send some static files, but that takes a special kind of route that is told exactly what route prefixes to look for and what directory on your server to look for files that might match URLs that are requested.  This can be done for static files that you specific locate in a directory by themselves (like .css files, for example) that you intend to send to the client when requested.  And, you have to use the right code to make that happen.  By default that never happens.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I made a mistake in my question which led to a misunderstanding. I understand, that the server side code is not sent to the client. So yes, it is not the whole `app.js`. But with ReactJS for example, the whole client-side code is given to the client. The routes are implemented in that code on the client. But when I want to build a restricted area, I feel insecure when the client knows the code of that area even if he is not logged in. So the real question would be: How to hide that client side code, until the user is logged in.

Comment: @henk - You can't hide logic that runs in the client.  Everything that runs in the client is visible to anyone who wants to do look at it.  If you want something to be private or secret, you have to implement that code on the server, not in client-side code.  Just like you can't do a login check in client code.  That has to be done on the server.

Comment: So if I want a simple admin panel for my app, there is no way to hide it? Except implementing it as a standalone app, which interacts with my first app through an API on the server only?

Comment: @henk - I don't know react.js myself, but conceptually every action the admin panel carries out has to be authenticated by the server to make sure it is coming from a properly authorized user.  It's your choice whether you dynamically load the admin panel only after the user has properly authenticated themselves or whether it's code is there all the time and you just hide the interface until they authenticate themselves.  Since all admin panel actions have to be authenticated on the server, there should be no vulnerability by exposing the client-side code to non-admins.

Comment: @henk - But, this assumes that all secure admin operations are actually implemented server-side and every client request is checked on the server for proper authentication.  Remember, that you can't ever put anything in client code that needs to be a secret.

Comment: I agree about the authentication, but still, I think it is more secure if a not authorized user, doesn't even know that there is an admin panel. If you don't even know about the existence, you will not have the idea to break into that admin panel. But if you say that it is possible to load such parts dynamically, then I just need to find out how.

Comment: @henk - Then, you would have to only dynamically load the admin panel after the user has authenticated.  That could conceptually be done by dynamically adding routes to your existing app after authentication or by just making a new app that exposes the admin functionality that is only loaded after auth.